# Multiple schematics in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

When there are multiple schematics opened in LTspice and you run one of them, all pages (plots and schematics) will be arranged automatically in small windows on the screen. I want to see only the schematic that I run along with its plot, not any other one.

How can I get LTspice to only show the running schematic and its plots?

Comment: You can just minimize or close unused plots and schematics. I manually drag schematic and plot side by side until I get an optimal view.

Comment: @pat the problem is that the applied manual arrangements will not be kept for later runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of LTspice.

Comment: @Kamran You can open two, or more, LTspice programs. You can run one simulation in one LTspice program and another simulation in another LTspice program.

Answer (score 2):

If the already accepted answer doesn't do it for you (thought it looks like it's selected) then consider that the quickest solution to your problem is to simply maximize any window inside the MDI. That will convert all of the opened windows as tabs. One click, that's all. I suppose that is what you expected? Personally, I open up multiple windows, unless I need to copy stuff between schematics.

We all have opinions, but if it makes your experience so bad then why not choose another simulator? There are others who are free.

Answer (score 2):

Plot Settings can be used and reloaded for individual simulation runs. For viewing schematics, you can always Tile or Cascade windows from the menu bar. I agree with the other suggestions that you can open multiple LTspice windows.

[image]

Comment: firstly, thanks for your suggestion. and secondly, thanks for the attached image that informed me about the possibility of using different plot planes.